# Changing ID type of a member in MailChimp

Tags: mailchimp

I'm using MailChimp v3.0.

What I want to achieve is to have members of lists been assigned consecutive numbers as theirs IDs.

The question is if it is possible to have a new list's member been assigned `id` of type `int` instead of MD5 hash? I'm digging through the documentation and cannot find a single word about lists customization.

If this cannot be done, I have a fall-back of creating custom table where next free `id` would be stored. Something like sequence object in Oracle databases. The next question is if it is possible to have custom tables.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. The ID of a member is the MD5 hash of their email, it's not something you get to choose. If you need some mapping from a custom ID to the email address, you'll need to keep it in your end.